# PowerShell Get-Help filename.ps1 only shows file name

Tags: powershell

In PowerShell 5.0 `Get-Help` does not show the comment based help for a script. Instead only the file name is printed.

For this code the value of the comment block is not displayed:

```
# dare.ps1
<# 
.SYNOPSIS
     The answer
.DESCRIPTION
     Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe, and Everything.
#>
"The answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe and Everything is {0}" -f 42
```

### Command

```
PS C:\> Get-Help .\dare.ps1
```

### Output

```
dare.ps1
```

Answer (score 5):

Either the opening of the comment based help needs to be on the first line, or there needs to be more space between the first comments or code and the comment based help block.

### Option 1 - Add line space

#### Code with extra space

```
# dare.ps1

<# 
.SYNOPSIS
     The answer
.DESCRIPTION
     Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe, and Everything.
#>
"The answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe and Everything is {0}" -f 42
```

### Option 2 - Put comment based help block first

#### Comment based help block first

```
<# 
.SYNOPSIS
     The answer
.DESCRIPTION
     Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe, and Everything.
#>
"The answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe and Everything is {0}" -f 42
```

### Result

```
NAME
    C:\dare.ps1

SYNOPSIS
    The answer


SYNTAX
    C:\dare.ps1 [<CommonParameters>]


DESCRIPTION
    Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe, and Everything.
```